# Trouble when installing 32-bit packages on a 64-bit system

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

I've recently re-installed my system as 64-bit, and am currently trying to get the Android SDK up. One of the packages required is `libsdl1.2debian:i386`. Trying to naively install this caused apt-get to try and uninstall most of the OS. Eventually I figured out, with some careful `aptitude` work, that the problem can be solved by downgrading a point-release on the 64-bit `libasound2` and `libgcrypt11` packages. For example, the version of `libasound2` installed was `1.0.25-1ubuntu10.1`, whereas the latest `:i386` version was `1.0.25-1ubuntu10`. Now, when trying to update my system, it claims everything is up-to-date, and there is no sign of the newer packages... what's going on? This should be handled better in some way...

Comment: Do you have the **ia32-libs** package installed?

Comment: @Aaron, that problem occurs when trying to install it.
Also, it turns out that the problem originated from installing the <tt>tikhonov-misc-precise</tt> PPA packages (in an attempt to fix the blue flash player tint issue).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the issue originated from installing various PPAs, such as `tikhonov-misc-precise`. This installs slightly-more-updated packages for AMD64, which breaks `:i386` packages which require an identical version.

Fixing:

1. Remove the PPAs
2. Install `aptitude`
3. Using `aptitude`, try to install the `ia32-libs` package - many packages will break.
4. Use the `b` key to find broken packages. At the bottom of the package details page in `aptitude`, available packages will be shown. If an older one is available - install it (using `i`).
5. When you're all done, only ubuntu-official packages should be installed, and you should be good to go.

I wish it weren't this complicated... recovering from a bad PPA seems to be quite a pain.